# Chrome cant POST to https, but GET using a self signed SSL-cert?

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, ssl, https

We have a site in a S3 bucket configured to serve static HTML. The HTML app is an AngularJS app. The AngularJS app requests its data with ajax through HTTPS with a self signed certificate to our backend API. All the GET requests work fine, but when we POST,PUT or DELETE in chrome the ajax requests get canceled.

All types of requests works in Firefox.

Our solution has been to disable HTTPS but that does not seem like a long term solution. Bought certificates is not an option for us.

We have noticed that the requests works in some versions of chrome. Is this something normal in chrome? Is there any way to avoid this?

Thanks for any kind of answer that might help us!

Comment: [This question](http://superuser.com/questions/632059/how-to-add-a-self-signed-certificate-as-an-exception-in-chrome) seems very relevant to your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Tyler! You are right! Chromes very much dislikes certificates that is not signed by a trusted authority.